# Start Splash Screen after initial App intro launch

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, splash-screen

I implemented an app intro which when first launched, takes the user through an introduction of the application.

This app intro only shows at the initial first launch of the application and ceases afterward. Is there a way I can implement my splashscreen to where the splashscreen will launch for subsequent launches?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do that

Comment: You can validate the app launch is first time or not by storing first time launch in Sharedpreferences. Every time app launches you need to check whether it is first time or not. And you can proceed. [This link will be helpful for you.](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here're my recommendation:

1. Always start your Splash screen as main Activity.
2. In `onResume()` method of Splash screen, look for a boolean in your
   `SharedPreferences` against a key (let say `"isFirstLaunch"`)
   indicating if the into has been shown before or not. If not, this is
   your first launch.
3. Now immediately launch your Intro Activity if its first launch from
   `onResume()` of Splash activity, and override Intro Activity's
   `onBackPressed()` or `onDestroy()` or `finish()` or inside your
   custom button click listener to save the boolean into
   `SharedPreferences` indicating it has been shown.
4. For every other launch, continue your normal flow of Splash.

This way, managing from Splash screen is easy.

Comment: Do you mind taking a look at my github to see where I went wrong? I'm still having issues doing this. https://github.com/AbanoubG/copticchurch-directory

Comment: I had a look on your code, what is the issue you're having?

Comment: The splash screen no longer appears after I implemented the app intro

Comment: For me it worked fine, I just tested your code.. Can you remove your app and install fresh?

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried it and no splash screen shows. Just the initial app intro

Comment: Okay, two changes required. 1 make your .Splash as main activity in manifest. 2. Launch `WelcomeActivity` from `Splash` instead of `MainActivity`.

Comment: Wonderful. Works perfectly now. Thank you Adil